# In Java, how can I generate a templated object from a type name?

Tags: java, templates, reflection

I'm trying to create a SpecificDatumReader for a class whose name is passed in as a string. I can create one of these classes, and I can get the Class of this class, but none of these actually allows me to create my templated object.

```
    String[] classList = conf.getClasslist(eventname);
    decoders = new LinkedList<SpecificDatumReader>();
    for (String className : classList)
    {
        Class<?> eventclass = Class.forName(className);
        Object holder = eventclass.newInstance();
        decoders.add(new SpecificDatumReader<WhatGoesHere?>(eventclass));
    }
```

Comment: Java doesn't have template types, and generics are a compile time type checking feature (see also *type erasure*).

Comment: Don't use raw types.

Comment: Given that (as Elliott said) generics are a compile type checking feature, I'm not convinced that you need to tell the program what the type parameter is when you're creating the object, since it won't get stored in your list anyway.  So just `new SpecificDatumReader<Object>(whatever)` should work fine.

Comment: I'm getting conflicting advice here. Shmosel insists that I shouldn't use raw types, but the other comments tell me that specifying is impossible. Does specifying <Object> do anything different than no specification at all?

Comment: @RobertRapplean It shuts up the compiler about raw types ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

1. Java doesn't have templates. The correct name for the syntax you posted is Generics.
2. The argument you're asking about is a compile-time constant (a class name), not a runtime variable.